# After Decompressing in a Vagrant Created machine cant run programs

Tags: vagrant, symlink, compression

I'm using a Vagrant script to create and install a ubuntu VM.

I require the use of a compiler that unfortunatly is not available in the apt repo and so, instead of having to compile it on the machine which takes come time i decided to compress with tar the full directory of other machine that i have using this site as reference

https://serverfault.com/questions/265675/how-can-i-zip-compress-a-symlink

All goes well on the installation, (it decompresses the tar to the /opt directory using sudo tar -xhzvf foo.tgz) but when trying to run the compiler nothing happens although all the symlinks are there (calling the exe in the .bin dir does nothing)

Any thoughts on what's happening?

Comment: have the files get the correct permission after untar ?

Comment: yes, using the flags said in that link (more specific -p) when it compresses it preserves permissions